# Align ImageButton to fill width and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an ImageButton like this one:

```
<ImageButton
   android:background="@drawable/ctg_a"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:id="@+id/cmdCategoryA" />
```

My layout has multiple of these ImageButtons inside a linearlayout (nested inside a scrollView). The Buttons should take 100% of the space available for their width, and use matching height so the ratio of the images (5:3) is not changed.

With my code, I get the image to fill the whole page in width, but in height the image uses its original size, which is too large and does not match the ratio.

So, currently, the image is something around 5:8 instead of 5:3. How do I reduce the height?

edit: could it have something to do with the context? Here is the code of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.mjz.test.MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/ctg_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/cmdCategoryA"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />         
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I made another approach with clearing the xml, and adding the buttons dynamically. My Code:

```
ImageButton cmdCategoryA;
LinearLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.categories_layout);
    setTitle("Kategorien");

    Configuration configuration = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
    int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp;

    cmdCategoryA = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
    layoutParams.width=screenWidthDp;
    layoutParams.height=(screenWidthDp/5)*3;
    cmdCategoryA.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    cmdCategoryA.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ctg_a));
    mainLayout.addView(cmdCategoryA);
}
```

This kind of works, only that the Image is not full width, but ~1/3 of the screen. screenWidthDp returns 360, which is correct for my nexus 5.

Do I have to add the type (dp/px/...) somewhere?

Comment: do you wish to reduce the height dynamically..?

Comment: @saran not needed, the activity is not generated dynamically, so everything I need is already available at design time. But when I change the scaleType, it does not change anything.

Comment: so you want to reduce the excess height of the imageview..to maintain a aspect ratio..?

Comment: @saran exactly, in xml

Comment: you can try android:scaleType="centerInside"..

Comment: @saran I tried all the different scaleTypes, no one did any change

Comment: Have you tried using `PercentRelativeLayout` with `layout_aspectRatio`?

Comment: @Abdullah that is new to me, can you provide me a link or example about that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentLayoutHelper.html. You need to add support library to your `build.gradle` like this `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'`

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm missing something. I'm sure there is a very simple way, and I think my mistake is the LayoutWidth of the ImageButton which causes the stretching.

Comment: Generally with scrollview if images are larger in size they tend to take complete space according to their original size. To solve this issue you should use image with smaller dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an appropriate way by myself:

I decided to add the controls programmatically, and used the following to resize the image.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you don't want the images to cover the whole width, reduce the width and height for example to 90%.
Also center the image for a good look.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can not do it in a only xml way...

First convert the drawable into Bitmap

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

then try to use:

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

i hope this helps..

**Edited :**

try this also:

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

while trying this do not set the height of the imageview to match_parent instead set it to warpcontent

Comment: instead of *0.8 ..use your requirement

Comment: thank you for your help, but with this I get the same result. width is perfect, but height is just way too much

Comment: one last way which i think might work, @Marcel try the updated answer with wrap_content as  imagebutton layout height